# Unexpected close tag in aws cdk deploy

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I am trying to create a CDK Code Construct for my python scripts, in stack i have added s3 and lambda.
When I am trying to execute cdk deploy, it is exiting after 0% progress or it is giving following error.
When i tried for s3 only it is working fine but when i added the lambda it is giving me error.

```
file_feed_lambda = _lambda.Function(
        self, id='MyLambdaHandler001',
        runtime=_lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_7,
        code=_lambda.Code.asset('lambda'),
        handler='lambda_function.lambda_handler',
    )

    bucket = s3.Bucket(self,
                       "FeedBucket-01")
```

[image]

Note : cdk diff and cdk synth are working properly

Comment: Where is line 12?

Comment: @Marcin dont know which line number it is referring, But Char : > not anywhere in my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently error which is showing is wrong i have updated the version of node and cdk to latest.
After update I have received the meaningful error which was socket time out.

After setting the proxy it worked for me.