# Unable to run "CDK Deploy" on Windows 10 , it throws an error on running CDK Deploy

Tags: deployment, aws-cdk

I have built a stack to deploy on my AWS Workspace, but after CDK Synth which does NOT throw any error, CDK Deploy fails to deploy the CF Template for the Stack. It throws an error. I am trying on a Windows machine.

Could you have a look and suggest me anything that could work. I am trying to learn AWS but keep getting stuck so it would be a big help if you can have a look at this .

Detailed Error Msg

```
[66%] success: Published <<>> (Removed the actual info)
[09:55:03] [66%] cached: From cache C:\MyStack\cdk.out.cache<<>>.zip
[09:55:03] [66%] upload: Upload s3://file-assets-bucket-dev/Test.zip
**[100%] fail: Unexpected close tag
Line: 94
Column: 7
Char: >**

❌ MyStack failed: Error: Failed to publish one or more assets. See the error messages above for more information.
at publishAssets (C:\aws-cdk\lib\index.js:374:73647)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at async CloudFormationDeployments.publishStackAssets (C:\aws-cdk\lib\index.js:381:87962)
at async CloudFormationDeployments.deployStack (C:\aws-cdk\lib\index.js:381:84233)
at async deployStack2 (C:\aws-cdk\lib\index.js:383:145458)
at async C:\aws-cdk\lib\index.js:383:128776
at async run (C:\aws-cdk\lib\index.js:383:126782)

❌ **Deployment failed: Error**: Stack Deployments Failed: Error: Failed to publish one or more assets. See the error messages above for more information.
at deployStacks (C:\aws-cdk\lib\index.js:383:129083)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at async CdkToolkit.deploy (C:\aws-cdk\lib\index.js:383:147507)
at async exec4 (C:\aws-cdk\lib\index.js:438:51799)
[09:55:24] Reading cached notices from C:.cdk\cache\notices.json

**Stack Deployments Failed: Error**: Failed to publish one or more assets. See the error messages above for more information.
[09:55:24] Error: Stack Deployments Failed: Error: Failed to publish one or more assets. See the error messages above for more information.
at deployStacks (C:\aws-cdk\lib\index.js:383:129083)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at async CdkToolkit.deploy (C:\aws-cdk\lib\index.js:383:147507)
at async exec4 (C:\aws-cdk\lib\index.js:438:51799)
```

**List of debugging that I have already tried so far and it has NOT worked yet , are listed below**.

1. One of my colleagues imported my stack and ran CDK synth and CDK Deploy for my stack through his Macbook and it worked fine, i.e. it created a CloudFormation template for my stack on the workspace successfully.
2. So, I deleted Virtual Env on my Windows machine , deleted CDK.out , Deleted CDK.context.json and re-created Virtual Env again and tried CDK deploy but no success, it still failed with same error.
3. Also installed latest version of CDK using npm install -g aws-cdk@latest
4. Tried running CDK DEPloy(after CDK synth) and got stuck with same error included below
5. Also, tried to generate a Log file using cdk deploy --verbose > log.txt but Log file is empty(i.e. 0 KB size)
6. Also ran this command , cdk deploy --no-previous-parameters

****Expected result**** : CDK Deploy should run successfully for my stack and deploy a CloudFormation Template(as per the Stack I have created) to the AWS Workspace``

Comment: see [Unexpected close tag in aws cdk deploy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68392241/unexpected-close-tag-in-aws-cdk-deploy) tldr: update nodejs & cdk npm packages. CDK requires nodejs & typescript to be installed, even if you're using Python